# Where is the bottleneck in my home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, raspberry-pi, sftp

My setup is as follows:

```
-Raspberry Pi 3
-Zinc by CnMemory external hdd
-FritzBox 7312
-Macbook Pro(early 2015)
```

The FritzBox is my router. The raspberry is connected to it via LAN cable, Wifi on it is disabled.
The external hdd is connected to the Pi via USB, running hdparm -Tt yields these results:

```
-Timing cached reads:   1248 MB in  2.00 seconds = 624.10 MB/sec
-Timing buffered disk reads:  90 MB in  3.06 seconds =  29.39 MB/sec
```

Last night I started to download the Kali Linux image since my Internet is not the fastest. Today I transferred it to my Macbook via SFTP using Cyberduck.

The problem is that I only had 4MB/s transferring speed. Should that not be way quicker? If yes where could the bottleneck be and what would be a way to get rid of it. If not where is the error in my thought process? Don't all of the connections allow way faster transfer speeds than 4MB/s?

[Edit]Aparently it is per file. I just transferred 2 files at the same time and both transferred at 4MB/s

Comment: Maybe the encryption. Try FTP or NFS or samba.